# Sending the keydown event does not work in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, automation, phantomjs, keypress

I tried this code with a web page which its content loaded dynamically when we press keydown. (like facebook)

The goal is to get all net traffic and print it to console.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: netlog.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];

    page.onLoadFinished      = function(req) {
        console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stiringify(req, undefined, 4));

    };
    page.open(url, function () {
        page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.keydown); 
    });
    page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
        console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req, undefined, 4));
    };

    page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
        console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4));
    };


    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        }
        phantom.exit();
    });

}
```

Comment: Did my answer help? Did you have any problems?

Comment: Yeah, the answer helped me thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, PhantomJS is asynchronous. You're opening two pages at the same time. When the second `page.open()` the loading of the first page is aborted. This means that your `page.sendEvent()` call is never executed.

If you want to see whether the event is doing something, you need to let the page load and after doing some action wait a little to see if there are requests:

```
if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: netlog.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];

    page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
        console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req, undefined, 4));
    };

    page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
        console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4));
    };


    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
            phantom.exit(1);
        }

        page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.keydown); 

        setTimeout(function(){
            phantom.exit();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```